# Error using Actions in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, action

I'm having an error using Actions in Selenium, this is my code:

```
   public class Actions_keys 
    {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void ebay() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",         "C:\\Appium\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.bshari.tk/Account/Login");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.id("Pk_UserId"));
//      ele.sendKeys("qwe");
        ele.click();
        act.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys("qwerty").build().perform();
    }
}
```

---

**Error:**

> org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST
>   /session/2ef57730-2920-461f-9f99-be201bfcc9bd/keys did not match a
>   known command Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75',
>   time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700' System info: host: 'Revanth', ip:
>   '192.168.1.11', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{moz:profile=C:\Users\revan\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.oYG6PBsXT6f9,
>   rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, page load=300000,
>   script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY,
>   specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false,
>   acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=52.0, platformVersion=10.0,
>   moz:processID=2104, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]

I am unsure how to fix this error and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do this instead of just `ele.sendKeys("QWERTY");`?

Comment: I ran the same code in firefox and it worked perfectly fine. Try with the latest selenium-java version 3.3.0 and latest Gecko Driver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases